# make the icon of the first open accordian in each section start with "-", right now they all start with "+"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
//Accordian jQuery
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.accordian-content').hide();
        $(".accordian .accordian-item:first-child .accordian-content").slideDown();
        $('.accordian-title').click(function () {
            const flag = $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').hasClass('accordian-title-icon-open');
            $(this).parents('.accordian').find('.accordian-title-icon').removeClass('accordian-title-icon-open');
            $(this).parents('.accordian').find('.accordian-content').not($(this).next('.accordian-content')).slideUp();
            $(this).next('.accordian-content').slideToggle();
            if (!flag) {
                $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').addClass('accordian-title-icon-open')

                //Add this code
               /* thisE = $(this)
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: thisE.offset().top -75 }, 'slow');
                }, 450)//Wait for toggle animation to finish */

            } else {
                $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').removeClass('accordian-title-icon-open')
            }

        });
    });
```

```css
.priority-lists {width:100%;}
        .accordian-title {
            width: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 20px 10px 20px 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .accordian-item {
            color: rgba(40, 150, 211, 1);
            margin: 10px auto;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 530px;
            background: #fff;
            border: solid 1px #f0f0f0;
            border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.29);
            -moz-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.29);
            box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.29);
            -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
            -moz-transition: all .1s ease;
            -o-transition: all .1s ease;
            transition: all .1s ease;
        }

        .accordian-item:hover {
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        }

        .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon {
            background: #dedede;
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            font-weight: 700;
            margin-right: 0;
            padding: 0 0 0 1px;
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: top;
            float: right;
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
            -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
            -o-transition: all .3s ease;
        }



            .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon:before {
                content: '+';
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                font-size: 21px;
                line-height: 24px;
                margin: -1px;
            }

        .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon-open:before {
            display: none;
        }

        .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon-open:after {
            content: '-';
            margin-top: -3px;
            margin-left: -1px;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .accordian-content {
            color: #3a3a3a;
            padding: 0 20px 20px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .accordian-content2 {
            color: #3a3a3a;
            padding: 0 20px 20px;
            text-align: left;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="priority-lists">
                <div class="accordian">

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>this is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                
                <h2>SECTION 2</h2>
                
 <div class="priority-lists">
                <div class="accordian">

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>this is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

I would like the icon for the first accordian of each section represent the open state (-) versus the current closed state icon (+). 
So when the the first open accordian is clicked it will close and icon will change accordingly. Further, if another accoridian is clicked it will open and the previously open accordian will close

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I can think of to do it:

1) just manually add the class "accordian-title-icon-open" to the first span in each accordian item.

2) add this line to your jQuery just after the slidedown line:

```
$(".accordian-item:first-child  .accordian-title-icon").addClass('accordian-title-icon-open');
```

Either way, three things I want to say:

1) your code seems overly cluttered (e.g. you add an inline style to each .accordian-content that you don't need since you hide them all in your jQuery

2) it is spelled accordion, not accordian. I don't say that to be anal, but I must have typed the wrong thing going through this code four or five times. Spell things correctly and your editors will thank you.

3) you may want to look into the checkbox hack for this sort of thing in the future. it does not require jQuery or any other outside libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can add below line to your code. It will find the visible `.accordian-content` and find the related `.accordian-item` and add the class `.accordian-title-icon-open` to that.

**This will help you if you are opening the random child of accordion.**

See the Snippet below:

```js
//Accordian jQuery
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.accordian-content').hide();
        $(".accordian .accordian-item:first-child .accordian-content").slideDown();
        /************ ADD BELOW LINE ******************/
        $(".accordian-content:visible").parent().find(".accordian-title-icon").addClass("accordian-title-icon-open");
        /************ ADD ABOVE LINE ******************/
        $('.accordian-title').click(function () {
            const flag = $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').hasClass('accordian-title-icon-open');
            
$(this).parents('.accordian').find('.accordian-title-icon').removeClass('accordian-title-icon-open');
            $(this).parents('.accordian').find('.accordian-content').not($(this).next('.accordian-content')).slideUp();
            $(this).next('.accordian-content').slideToggle();
            if (!flag) {
                $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').addClass('accordian-title-icon-open')

                //Add this code
               /* thisE = $(this)
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: thisE.offset().top -75 }, 'slow');
                }, 450)//Wait for toggle animation to finish */

            } else {
                $(this).find('.accordian-title-icon').removeClass('accordian-title-icon-open')
            }

        });
    });
```

```css
.priority-lists {width:100%;}
        .accordian-title {
            width: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 20px 10px 20px 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .accordian-item {
            color: rgba(40, 150, 211, 1);
            margin: 10px auto;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 530px;
            background: #fff;
            border: solid 1px #f0f0f0;
            border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.29);
            -moz-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.29);
            box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.29);
            -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
            -moz-transition: all .1s ease;
            -o-transition: all .1s ease;
            transition: all .1s ease;
        }

        .accordian-item:hover {
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        }

        .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon {
            background: #dedede;
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            font-weight: 700;
            margin-right: 0;
            padding: 0 0 0 1px;
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: top;
            float: right;
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
            -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
            -o-transition: all .3s ease;
        }



            .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon:before {
                content: '+';
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                font-size: 21px;
                line-height: 24px;
                margin: -1px;
            }

        .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon-open:before {
            display: none;
        }

        .accordian .accordian-item .accordian-title .accordian-title-icon-open:after {
            content: '-';
            margin-top: -3px;
            margin-left: -1px;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .accordian-content {
            color: #3a3a3a;
            padding: 0 20px 20px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .accordian-content2 {
            color: #3a3a3a;
            padding: 0 20px 20px;
            text-align: left;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="priority-lists">
                <div class="accordian">

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>this is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                
                <h2>SECTION 2</h2>
                
 <div class="priority-lists">
                <div class="accordian">

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>This is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordian-item">
                        <div class="accordian-title">TITLE<span class="accordian-title-icon"></span></div>
                        <div class="accordian-content" style="display: none;">
                            <p>this is a sentence</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```